# Simple string addition in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing, web-scraping

This is something I wasn't expecting.

I'm using anemone to count links in pages (anemone is a web spider framework for ruby)

Its pretty straightforward, but why won't this work?

```
anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    @myLinks =[]
      page.links.each_with_index do |link,index|
        puts "HOWDY PARDNER"
        @tempLink =(link.to_s + ",")
        @myLinks[index] = @tempLink
      end
end
```

The part in question is the addition of link.to_s  +","

The reason I'm doing this addition is that links.to_s comes down as an entire string with no spaces. I'd like to sepsrate them with a , so I can use .split() later.

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: why would you need to split them if you already have them in the array?! and what is the problem (error)?

Comment: @mkk Sorry. The array is posted via json as a string. I'm having trouble getting it back into an array from that string and this is why Im using .split (java) or .join (ruby)

Comment: did you consider using .to_json method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to split (you mean `join`?) them later you don't need to add ",":

```
@my_links = ["Link 1", "Link 2", "Link 3"]
@my_links.join(", ")
#=> "Link 1, Link 2, Link 3"
@my_links.to_sentence
#=> "Link 1, Link 2, and Link 3"
```

That's all you need, I think.

```
anemone.on_every_page do |page|
  @my_links = page.links.join(", ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need json array just consider using

```
 array.to_json
```

method

Answer (score 0):

You can turn json objects back into ruby objects using the following:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(some_json)
```